# Regular expression validation for string [01:3:14/ 1:8:20]

Tags: asp.net

I am pulling my head for below problem.

I have text box in my application that will take time in the format 1(days):23(hours): 15(minutes).
I want to apply validation for this field so it will take string in the format [01:05:15/ 1:4:30] only.

Please tell me the workaround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use separator like below.

```
^([0-2]\d?|3[01]):([0-1]\d?|2[0-3]):(00?|15|30|45)$
```

If you need more information check below.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also i want to specify minimum and maximum limits like (days[0-31]):(hours[0-23): (minutes[0/15/30/45]). what will be workaround for this.